# Pegar valores de uma Array e implementar dentro do Json usando php

Tags: php, json, array

Como eu faço pra pegar os valores dessa array

```
 array(2) {["Premium"]=>array(3) {["valor"]=> string(3) "100" ["quantidade"]=> string(3) "200" ["status"]=> string(1) "1" } ["Arena"]=> array(3) { ["valor"]=> string(2) "50" ["quantidade"]=> string(3) "200" ["status"]=> string(1) "1" } }
```

e modificar os valores do seguinte json

```
{"3":{"tipo":"Premium","valor":"100","quantidade":"200","vendas":"0","status":"1"},"1":{"tipo":"Arena","valor":"50","quantidade":"200","vendas":"0","status":"1"}}
```

De acordo com os seus tipos, por exemplo a Array [Premium] altera os valores do json que contenha o "tipo":"Premium".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi você quer alterar todos os valores do`json`usando de parâmetro os valores do `array`. Portanto criei uma solução que passa por todos os elementos do `json` e verifica se o atributo 'tipo' está contido no índice do `array`. Se estiver, altera os valores do `json` usando os valores e os índices do `array`:

**Código comentado**

```
    $array = [
        'Premium' => ['valor' => '350', 'quantidade' => '50', 'status' => '1'],
        'Arena' => ['valor' => '250', 'quantidade' => '10', 'status' => '1']
    ];
    $json = '{"3":{"tipo":"Premium","valor":"100","quantidade":"200","vendas":"0","status":"1"},"1":{"tipo":"Arena","valor":"50","quantidade":"200","vendas":"0","status":"1"}}';

    $json = json_decode($json, true); // tranforma o json em array para a comparação

    $keys = array_keys($array); // pega as chaves do array

    // loop em cada elemento
    foreach($json as $key => $val){
        // se houver o indice no array que for igual ao tipo, iguala os valore do array
        if(in_array($val['tipo'], $keys)){
            $json[$key]['valor'] = $array[$val['tipo']]['valor']; // altera o valor
            $json[$key]['quantidade'] = $array[$val['tipo']]['quantidade']; // altera a quantidade
            $json[$key]['status'] = $array[$val['tipo']]['status']; // altera o status
        }
    }
    print_r(json_encode($json));
```

Comment: Quando eu altero o valor na array o mesmo não é modificado no json!

Comment: @Joãopedro desculpa, é o sono! =) Está la!

Comment: Muito obrigado!